# Cascading ForeignKey relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

newbie here, I am trying to make a simple ForeignKey relationship in Django.
Meat <-- Beef <-- nutrition data.  I keep getting the error

```
<class 'foods_data.models.Nutrition_Data'> has no ForeignKey to <class'foods_data.models.Nutrition_Data'>
```

Here is my Models Code.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name

class Food_Item(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
   food_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.food_name

class Nutrition_Data(models.Model):
   food_item = models.ForeignKey(Food_Item)
   nut_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   nut_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nut_name
```

Comment: did you add the `ForeignKey` _after_ you did a syncdb?

Comment: No I I fixed it, thank you for the help though. Turns out is was an issue with doing a TabularInline.